# How do synonyms work retroactively behind the scene?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, architecture

I am implementing a simular tag system on my site so I'd like some insights on how the synonym (alias) system works with regard to retroactively making changes.

For example let's say there are 100 questions with tag A, 100 questions with tag B.

Later, it is decided that B is an alias of A. What happens to the 100 questions with B? Do they all get definitively converted to A?

Later, somebody realizes this was a mistake, and makes B independent again. What happens now?

And what if someone realizes that B is better suited to be the master tag, so now A is a synonym of B.

Answer (score 1):

**They don't work retroactively at all.**

Tag synonyms only affect new questions. Moderators have tools that allow them to re-tag many questions at once, but without this kind of intervention (or manually editing each question by normal users), old questions stay tagged as they were.